# Clarifying 'new version' of <X app>

Tags: discussion

It is my understanding that one of the goals of SE is for Q&As to be able to withstand the test of time in terms of their value to future readers. With this in mind (and assuming that the 'new gmail compose' won't always be so *new*), I'm wondering if there is a way to clarify/make explicit what is meant by 'old version' of X and 'new version' of X other than leaving the reader to look up application updates relative to the date of the original post.

This might be *doubly* helpful in instances (such as the question below re. Google Maps) in which the "new" application is in an 'invite only' stage.

Examples of where this may be helpful:

- [Can I create/view custom maps on the new Google Maps?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44960/can-i-create-view-custom-maps-on-the-new-google-maps)
- [Is there any way to improve Gmail's new compose?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42613/is-there-any-way-to-improve-gmails-new-compose)

One thought would simply be to include screenshots when the questions pertain to changes to the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if there is a way to clarify/make explicit what is meant by 'old version' of X and 'new version' of X other than leaving the reader to look up application updates relative to the date of the original post.

Screenshots should be how it must be done, especially considering very few(if at all any) web applications explicity display their version number. Enforcing this, however is near close to impossible, we can probably nudge the OP to include a screenshot.